# How to test DDL change

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing

I have a piece of functionality configuring audit feature of the application (MySQL databases). Here is what it does:
 - get all the database tables structure
 - create corresponding audit table (or modify existing)
 - recreate main table triggers capturing any data change

Now I am thinking about how to write the test of this. I created live integration test modifying the db structure, running this audit config ad checking its correctness but this is not the test I can include in the application (it modifies the real database). 
Is it actually possible to unit test such feature and  how if yes? How to mimic and verify the DDL change?

Comment: Could you run it against an in-memory database such as Derby in your unit tests?

Comment: Nope I can't. DDL syntax is quite database specific so I won't run in other database without changes, I tried H2 so far and it fails.

Comment: I can imagine just 1 way of testing it right now, namely verifying the number of tables, columns and triggers (the correctness of the audit stuff) after full install. It tests the result rather that the functionality itself but that's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To make this done I decided to test query generation ( their correctness) instead. I extracted all SQL statements (static and dynamic) to separate methods and then used partial mocking (Mockito) to execute those methods and check if they generating SQL statements as expected. This way I don't need to run anything in real and still have 90% of coverage what was the real goal here. The key part was to separate all SQL calls from the main method to enable partial mocking.